# UITableViewCells disappears randomly on drag after resize another row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView. I use this code to resize the selected row:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    ....
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ICSceneDetailViewTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:IC_CELL_SCENE_EDITOR_CELL];
    ...
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(int) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == nil)
        return 0;

    if (self.scenes != nil) {
        return self.scenes.count;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ICSceneDetailViewTableViewCell *cell = (ICSceneDetailViewTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IC_CELL_SCENE_EDITOR_CELL forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ICSceneDetailViewTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:IC_CELL_SCENE_EDITOR_CELL];
    }
    ICScene *scene = [self.scenes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [cell.titleTextField setText:scene.title];

    return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([indexPath row] == self.selectedRow) {
        return 250;
    }

    if (IS_IPAD) {
         return 80;
    }
    else {
         return 40;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

BUT, after selecting any row (name it A, and A become resized):

- if I drag another row (name it B) then randomly other rows disappears (except A).
- if I scroll tableview and back to drag on same row (B) then, again randomly, other(s) cell(s) disappear(s), but not always the same(s).

if I comment **heightForRowAtIndexPath** then drag behavior is normal, but row can't be resized :(

I already searched many similar answers (adjusting selectedBackgroundView on cell, backgroundView cell, drawRect on cell, etc) but no one solution/workaround works for this simple (i think) code.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't see anywhere in cellForRowAtIndexPath where the code is sensitive to height.

Comment: You are right, **cellForRowAtIndexPath** doesn't have any code related to cell's height; is there just to show a complete code. Inside **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** there is a call to **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** which triggers eventually **heightForRowAtIndexPath**.

Comment: But if your enlarged cell rolls off the screen and back on it needs to be recreated by cellForRowAtIndexPath with it's greater height, no??

Comment: cell is recreated but **heightForRowAtIndexPath** is called too. The cell's height is fine. The question is: why another(s) cell(s) disappears randomly on drag if **heightForRowAtIndexPath** returns multiple values ?

Comment: The larger cells are overlaying the adjacent ones?

Comment: No. All cells remains on his size. If you override **setFrame** on UITableViewCells you will notice that size is correct. This problem happens inclusive when you scrolls on UITableView and all rows has same heights. Disappearing rows sometimes are contiguous, sometimes aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeh, answering my own question.

I found an alternative to resize selected UITableViewCell without calling to **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths**.

Replacing **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** with:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

refreshes visible rows without calling **cellForRowAtIndexPath**. Imho the problem where dequeuing cells on every row being reloaded.

The resulting code is:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

So, automagically there isn't any disappearing row :)